# Getting a Windows ISO from Microsoft using Wget?

Tags: windows, iso-image

How do I get a windows ISO officially from Microsoft using Wget?

I'm creating a USB Flash Script which flashes ISO's to USBs. Any Idea?

Comment: You don’t? Furthermore, Microsoft updates the Windows ISOs relatively frequently, so a hard-coded path is a bad idea anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft does not officially provide direct URLs for its Windows ISOs,
preferring to give you the URL of its Media Creation Tool.
The direct URLs exist, but you will need to use a third-party website for
finding them.

An example for such websites is
[Download Windows 10 ISO Files (Direct Download Links)](https://www.itechtics.com/windows-10-download-iso/).

Note that you will need to update your script anytime that Microsoft
posts a new version of its ISO, which would be problematic for you.

Comment: Yeah I'm willing to do that.I'll frequently have to update linux ISO's as well, so it fine.